# Merging rows in a dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input data

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", 1, 1, "on"),
  ("1", 2, 2, "off"),
  ("1", 2, 5, "off"),
  ("1", 5, 5, "on"),
  ("1", 5, 6, "off"),
  ("2", 1, 1, "off"),
  ("2", 1, 2, "off"),
  ("2", 2, 2, "on"),
  ("2", 3, 4, "off"),
  ("2", 5, 7, "off"),
  ("2", 8, 10, "on"),
  ("2", 11, 11, "on"),
  ("2", 11, 12, "off"),
  ("3", 1, 12, "off")
).toDF("id", "start", "end", "sw")
```

I'm trying to merge rows using groupBy and mapGroups.

Desired output

```
1 1 5 on
1 5 6 on
2 1 2 off
2 2 7 on
2 8 10 on
2 11 12 on
3 1 12 off
```

The logic is as follows. Every off row is merged into the previous on row. If the first or only value is off, I get a single off row. Start is from first row, end from last row. The data shoud be sorted by start and end.

Here is what I have so far

```
df
  .as[Row]
  .groupByKey(_.id)
  .mapGroups{case(k, iter) => Row.merge(iter)}
```

I group the data by id and then try to iterate other the values.

```
case class Row(id:String, start:Int, var end:Int, sw:String)

object Row {
  def merge(iter: Iterator[Row]): ListBuffer[Row] = {
    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Row]
    var bufferRow = Row("", 0, 0, "")
    for(row <- iter){
      if(listBuffer.isEmpty) bufferRow = row
      else if(row.sw == "off") bufferRow.end = row.end
      else if(row.sw == "on") {
        listBuffer += bufferRow
        bufferRow = row
      }
    }
    if(listBuffer.isEmpty) listBuffer += bufferRow
    listBuffer
  }
}
```

My output

```
[WrappedArray([1,5,6,off])]
[WrappedArray([2,11,12,off])]
[WrappedArray([3,1,12,off])]
```

I already accomplished something similar using window functions and cumulative sum. Here I'm trying to learn a new approach.

Using spark 2.2, scala 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution is almost right, just need some adjustments

First, as your method `Row.merge` returns a list of Rows instead of a Row, you should use [flatMapGroups](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html#flatMapGroups%5BU%5D(f:org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapGroupsFunction%5BK,V,U%5D,encoder:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) to explode your list to different records in your Dataset:

```scala
df
  .as[Row]
  .groupByKey(_.id)
  .flatMapGroups { case (k, iter) => Row.merge(iter) }
```

Next, let's dive into your `Row.merge` method.

You create an empty `bufferRow` that you populate at first iteration of your loop over `iter` with statement `if (listBuffer.isEmpty) bufferRow = row`. However, condition in this statement is true for all iterations, that's why your output contains only the latest rows of each group. So this statement should be removed. To initialize your `bufferRow`, you can just call `iter.next()`:

```scala
... = new ListBuffer[Row]
var bufferRow = iter.next()
for(row <- iter) { ...
```

As iterator comes from a groupBy, it contains at least one element, thus first call of `iter.next()` doesn't throw exception. And as the call to `.next()` method remove the first element of the iterator, the loop after doesn't reprocess this first element.

Next, the last statement of your method before return statement is `if (listBuffer.isEmpty) listBuffer += bufferRow`. There should not be a condition for this statement.

Indeed, in your loop, you populate `bufferRow` then you add it to the `listBuffer` only when the currently processed row has "sw" field set to "on". And this currently processed row becomes the new `bufferRow`. It means that the last `bufferRow` is never saved in `listBuffer`, except when `listBuffer` is empty. So the last lines of your `merge` method should be:

```scala
...
    bufferRow = row
  }
}
listBuffer += bufferRow
```

We now have the complete `merge` method:

```scala
def merge(iter: Iterator[Row]): ListBuffer[Row] = {
  val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Row]
  var bufferRow = iter.next()
  for (row <- iter) {
    if (row.sw == "off") bufferRow.end = row.end
    else if (row.sw == "on" ) {
      listBuffer += bufferRow
      bufferRow = row
    }
  }
  listBuffer += bufferRow
}
```

And running this code gives you the following result, reordered by id and start columns:

```
+---+-----+---+---+
|id |start|end|sw |
+---+-----+---+---+
|1  |1    |5  |on |
|1  |5    |6  |on |
|2  |1    |2  |off|
|2  |2    |7  |on |
|2  |8    |10 |on |
|2  |11   |12 |on |
|3  |1    |12 |off|
+---+-----+---+---+
```

*Final Note: you should be careful of iterator ordering if you run this code on partitioned datasets, I'm not sure that the Spark's `groupBy` method keeps ordering of rows in grouped by iterator. Maybe it is wiser to reorder iterator with `.toSeq.sortBy(...)` before itering over it.*